# How to write a model with a nested array in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am writing a new class in spring boot where I need to write a modal class in which there will be a sub modal classes(I mean an array with a nested arrays), but when I try to run it I am getting the sub modal class names as attributes not the real attributes which I mentioned in sub modals.

**ChangeBin Model**

```
public class Changebin implements Serializable{

@Field(value = "Change_bin_Past")
private ChangebinPast changebinpast;

@Field(value = "Change_bin_Present")
private ChangebinPresent changebinpresent;

// Getter / Setters

}
```

**ChangebinPast -- Sub Model**

```
public class ChangebinPast implements Serializable {

@Field(value = "ID_A")
private String ID_A;

@Field(value = "ID_B")
private String ID_B;

// Getter / Setters

}
```

**Changebinpresent -- Sub Model**

```
public class ChangebinPresent implements Serializable {

@Field(value = "ID_A1")
private String ID_A1;

@Field(value = "ID_B1")
private String ID_B1;

// Getter / Setters
}
```

**Expected** :

```
ChangeBin [
   {
      ID_A : "",
      ID_B : ""
   },
   {
     ID_A1:  "",
     ID_B1: ""
   }
]
```

But got like this :

```
ChangeBin [
   {
      changebinpast: "",
       changebinpresent : ""
   },
   {
     changebinpast:  "",
     changebinpresent : ""
   }
]
```

Comment: What is a 'modal'? And a 'modal class'? Do you mean *model?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two set two fields `changebinpast` and `changebinpresent` which will be holding `ID_A` and `ID_A1` respectively, since `ID_A` is a property of `ChangebinPast` it will be held only by `ChangebinPast` which in turn is a property of `Changebin`.

Preferably you should reconsider changing the expect output.